# how I can make sql_select_limit takes precedence over limit (not the opposite)?

Tags: mysql

I want to force MySQL to make sql_select_limit take precedence over limit clause for any query.
for example, I set sql_select_limit=10 and I execute a query like "SELECT * FROM table limit 50"
I want as a result 10, not 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_select_limit says:

> If a `SELECT` has a `LIMIT` clause, the `LIMIT` takes precedence over the value of `sql_select_limit`.

That's the behavior supported by MySQL Server.

You would have to change the source code of MySQL Server to make it behave differently.

I suggest you write SQL queries as you would want them to behave.